# How to validate divisible of TextBox in MVC asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, fluent

Is it possible validating textbox in this case? The value in this TextBox ( `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstSetList[i].Amount)`) must be divisible by another value - Pack in this case (`@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstSetList[i].Pack)`).

I tried to use Fluent Validation, but there is a problem with **client-side validation**. Maybe it can be done without fluent validation. Only with basic DataAnnotation?

Here is the code of view:

```
@model FP.WebUI.ViewModels.DataItemVm

<h3>
    What kind of currencies you currently own?
</h3>
<br />
<div>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstSetList.FirstOrDefault().Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstSetList.FirstOrDefault().Pack)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstSetList.FirstOrDefault().Amount)
            </th>
        </tr>

        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < Model.FirstSetList.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstSetList[i].Name)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FirstSetList[i].Name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstSetList[i].Pack)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FirstSetList[i].Pack)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstSetList[i].Amount)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
            <input type="submit" value="Confirm" class="btn btn-success" />
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

---

**UPDATE**
I was trying to use Remote Annotation, however chrome doesn't send any information to my JsonResult Method and i don't know why.

My ViewModel:

```
.
.
.
    [Remote("Divisibility", "Account", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "Value is incorrect.")]
            public int Amount { get; set; }
.
.
.
```

My View:

```
.
.
.
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < Model.FirstSetList.Count; i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstSetList[i].Name)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FirstSetList[i].Name)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstSetList[i].Pack)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FirstSetList[i].Pack)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstSetList[i].Amount)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstSetList[i].Amount)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
                <input type="submit" value="Confirm" class="btn btn-success" />
            }
        </table>
    </div>
```

My Controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Divisibility(int valueToCheck)
    {
        var value = User.Identity.GetUserId().Where(x => x.Equals("qqqqq"));
//I know that this condition does not make sense, but this was only for test.
//Anyway like i said, chrome doesn't send anything to this method.

        return Json(value == null);
    }
```

Comment: Just check the validity server side as well, and post an error if it isn't correct.

Comment: It's not good enough because application will validate data after you press SUBMIT, i'd like to do this before.

Comment: So write some JavaScript for it. It won't be hard.

Comment: If you're looking for complex client-side validation logic, something like the jQuery Validation plugin may be useful to you.  ASP.NET MVC might even already come packaged with it.

Comment: Im using jQuery Validation, it works with DataAnnotation, right?

Answer (score 0):

The longer solution, and maybe better, would be to create your own validator in javascript using the same validators that MVC is using.  But, to something someone else mentioned, server side validation.  Use DataAnnotations with the Remote attribute and you can accomplish the same.

http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/asp-net-mvc-remote-validation-for-multiple-fields-with-additionalfields-property

You will create a server method to do the validation but the front end will be calling it.  The link I provided should give you all that you need.

Comment: I dont know why it doesn't work. Check my UPDATE above.

Comment: I assume your validation is on your Account controller.  Have you tried changing the 'amount' text in the textbox?  Typically, the validation fires when someone is changing a value.  If this is the case, then on load you would have to make it fire.